# Specific Data Extraction from a form (PDF or TIFF file)

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Is there a way I can train PDF documents to extract only the information (text) that I need using Google Cloud Platform.

[image: 1]

Like in the form above, I only want to extract text:
NAME OF COMMITTEE : SCOTT WALKER INC

Comment: So far I have used google cloud Document AI to extract the texts from PDFs but this  extracts text from entire document which is not what I need. I only need to extract texts that I choose to based on certain criteria.

Comment: @AITool you can also do that in document AI as long as you provide a bounding box https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/TableExtractionParams

Comment: If I am not wrong, I have to describe bounding box for all the forms to extract custom info. I want to train with documents so  that next time I upload another document, it would extract only the relevant info.